# How to create a view that gets information from 2 other databases?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I have 2 lotus notes databases which have basically the same information: employee data. As there are too many documents, our team thought it would be better to have all data splitted in two DBs. Also, data of both databases use a form with the same name and design, called frmEmployeeInfo.

The client wants a third database with a view that will contain data (documents) from both databases I mentioned before. I know I can use, for example, outlines to open a view of another database but...is it possible to create a view in this third database that shows documents from other 2 DBs? I'm not sure if this is 'doable'. I don't want to copy documents from the databases into this 3rd. database because I think the database will be very slow, as there will be a lot of documents.

Do you have any kind of suggestion about how can I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How many documents are you talking about? There are companies with hundreds of thousands of employees that keep employee information in a single database.

Comment: About 20,000 documents.

Comment: Unless you are running on a really old version of Notes and Domino (R 4.6 or earlier) or on a ridiculously under-powered server, there is no reason to split that into two databases. Whoever suggested doing that is literally 15 years out of date in their assessment of Notes and Domino scalability.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in classic Notes. But you should be able to do it in XPages (or through a web interface you create).

How big is the database? I have Notes databases with millions of documents, I don't see a need to split them into two, that sounds like a terrible design if you want to access all documents easily.

Comment: Couldn't he do something like an @dblookup and specify the other databases to search in?

Comment: Hi, Karl. First of all, thank you so much for answering.

I will have about 20,000 documents or more in the view. As the server is in the US but users are around world, it's very slow to access the database in the server (I keep asking them to access it through local replicas). Also, I deleted some columns of the view to improve performance (even in local replicas it was very slow).

So, do you think with this amount of documents would be good to keep it simple with a view with all documents?

Comment: Also, Karl, I developed a solution with Xpages: I added a tabbed panel with 2 tabs (each tab for each database view). However, I was thinking how to show this Xpage in client-server application, as it's not possible to open the Xpages from an outline, for example (I can be wrong, as I'm new in this Xpages functionalities).

Thank you very much again.

Comment: @Zach you can't do a dblookup in view formulas.

Comment: About the slow access... Do you have reader names fields on the documents and/or is it a categorized view with the 'show single category' feature so normal users see only their own information, while others with extra rights see all?

Comment: Absolutely, I have one database with 1.6+ million documents and over 100 views. Yes, that's a lot of views... But if you just design things correctly that's not a huge issue assuming you have a properly configured and maintained server. You can do many things to improve performance.
Splitting the database into multiple ones won't address the issue with slow connection from outside the US, you need to solve that as a separate problem.
If you look at http://i.imgur.com/9i5Xe3D.jpg you can see that I in just this view have over 750,000 documents...

Comment: And to elaborate on Rich's comment about readers fields, are you perhaps using time sensitive formulas in teh view, i.e. @Today or @Now? That will kill view performance. Only 20,000 documents is nothing.

Comment: Hi! I'm not using sensitive formulas. Richard, I don't use readers field in this one, so everybody will have access to everybody's information. Then, after reading all comments, I realized that the best option is to keep all documents in one database and I'll do it right now. They also have the option of working with replicas, so they could access databases locally and it won't be slow.
Thank you everybody for your great help!

Comment: About slow access. this could also be a network problem. have you checked how fast the server can be accessed from the outside ?